# Speeding up the query execution

Tags: php, mysql

I have table with millions of record from am extracting some thousands of rows to temp table even if query on temp table with simple where it is taking hours to get me the result , does any know how i can speed up query processing time??

Query is something like this

```
 Select col_name col1, col_name2 col2 from tbl_temp where col_name3 = 'value' and
 col_name4 = 'value' order by col_name desc limit 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure col_name3, col_name4  and col_name has correct indexing, and also, if possible, partritioned by date

Comment: no i can't add those columns for indexing they contain duplicate entries.

Comment: @somu.web: You *can* index columns that contain duplicates, as long as you don't try to set them as primary or unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't added indexes to your temporary table, you should.

Comment: ya i have added indexes to temp table for the col_name3

Answer (score 0):

Try `explain`ing the query. It will give you lots of information about how the query is executed, including how many rows it has to go through and whether or not it can use indexes.

```
EXPLAIN Select col_name col1, col_name2 col2 from tbl_temp where col_name3 = 'value' and col_name4 = 'value' order by col_name desc limit 2;
```